# How can I format SQL with Spring Boot 3

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I successfully make my tests to print SQLs and parameters with following logging levels.

```xml
    <logger name="org.hibernate.SQL" level="DEBUG"/> <!-- show SQL -->
    <logger name="org.hibernate.orm.jdbc.bind" level="TRACE"/>
```

And I tried to make the SQL formatted with following configuration and I failed.

```yaml
spring:
  jpa:
    properties:
      hibernate.format_sql: true # seems not work...
```

How can I format the SQL with Spring Boot 3?

Answer (score 1):

The full property path is `spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format_sql`, so you simply have to move it one level down in your application.yml:

```
spring:
  jpa:
    properties:
      hibernate:
        format_sql: true
```

However this approach (logging to standard output) [is not recommend here!](https://www.baeldung.com/sql-logging-spring-boot#1-to-standard-output)